# how to access quickblox content swift2?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, swift2, quickblox

**I am trying to upload a file image to the content but i get this error.**

> error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has
>   occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a
>   secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x162007a0
>   {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has
>   occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a
>   secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802,
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 3, values = (     0 :
>      1 :    2 :  )},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/}},
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/,
>   NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type
>   = immutable, count = 3, values = (    0 :   1 :      2 :
>    )},
>   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0,
>   NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/}

Comment: Hi kader, do you use iOS 9? It might be ATS problem. Please take a look at QB repo https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code to upload file and it worked perfectly.

```
let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

QBRequest.TUploadFile(imageData, 
                      fileName: "testimage.png", 
                      contentType: "image/png", 
                      isPublic: false, 
                      successBlock: {(response: QBResponse!, uploadedBlob: QBCBlob!) in 
                      /** You get success with updated blob **/
                      }, statusBlock: {(request: QBRequest?, status: QBRequestStatus?) in 

                      },
                      errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in 

                      })
```